# Why does Google show an incorrect website snapshot?

Tags: html, url, https, snapshot

[image]Google does not display the usual snapshot with time of visit, instead it shows in one line (see pic):

```
// Require https 
if ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] != "on") { 
    $url = "https://". $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    header("Location: $url"); 
    exit; 
}
```

I have deleted this code from the index.html page, however it still shows this as a snapshot of the page. The Google listing of the site is not good, not sure if this is related.

Does anybody knows a solution to this issue?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because SEO questions are off-topic. This question might be suitable for https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ (but do check their help center and search their existing questions before asking there)